# add jframe in system tray on the click of cross not in the case of minimize button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, system-tray, windowlistener

```
frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        if (e.getNewState() == ICONIFIED) {
            try {
                tray.add(trayIcon);
                frameLogin.setVisible(false);
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

});
```

this will add my application in system tray but i want to add my application in system tray when user clicked on cross not in the case of minimize

Comment: please for why reason is there code line tray.add(trayIcon);

Comment: I'd be ... trayIcon.setImage(), notice there should be good idea to notify user about changes by using trayIcon.displayMessage(), because most of Native OS's grouping those (Icons in System_Tray) Object to separate menu

Comment: actually i add this line so when user clicked on any button like minimize and cross then application is added to system tray and trayIcon contains image which i showed in system tray

Comment: [then where is the problem, theoretically all about is described in Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: mKorbel, i just want to know that is there any way to differentiate close and minimized button as lot's of application do like Skype

because when i click on minimized button it'll add my application to system tray and i don't want to do this

Comment: yes read methods for WindowListener implemented in API and together with important methods - DefaultCloseOperations for JFrame

Comment: yes i am doing that but i think that it'll be a better idea to ask question than do google about it

Comment: :-) o.k. then you have waiting for someone that collect my comments to one answer, but I'm think that System Tray will be created together with application (sure couldn't be visible) to avoids confusing user

Comment: no it's not like i'm waiting to some one to answer my problem.... i just want to know is there really a way to differentiate minimized and cross button because if i try to stop one operation it somehow effect other...

Comment: again yes read methods for WindowListener implemented in API (each of them react to another event) and together with important method - DefaultCloseOperations for JFrame (to avoid terminating current JVM)

Comment: yes i am reading the link that you shared in comment and also i'm using DefaultCloseOperations to avoid terminating JVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mKorbel says, `WindowListener` + `DefaultCloseOperation` works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class SystemTrayTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      return;
    }
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    BufferedImage i= new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = i.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(2, 2, 12, 12);
    g.dispose();
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    final TrayIcon icon   = new TrayIcon(i, "TRAY", popup);

    Handler h = new Handler(tray, icon);
    frame.addWindowStateListener(h);
    frame.addWindowListener(h);

    MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("OPEN");
    item1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        tray.remove(icon);
      }
    });
    MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("EXIT");
    item2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tray.remove(icon);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.dispose();
        //System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    popup.add(item1);
    popup.add(item2);
  }
}

class Handler extends WindowAdapter {
  private final SystemTray tray;
  private final TrayIcon icon;
  public Handler(SystemTray tray, TrayIcon icon) {
    super();
    this.tray = tray;
    this.icon = icon;
  }
  private void addTrayIconDisposeFrame(JFrame frame) {
    try {
      tray.add(icon);
      frame.dispose();
      //frame.setVisible(false);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  @Override public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("ICONIFIED");
    if (e.getNewState() == Frame.ICONIFIED) {
      addTrayIconDisposeFrame((JFrame) e.getSource());
    }
  }
  @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("windowClosing");
    addTrayIconDisposeFrame((JFrame) e.getSource());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, in your answer windowClosing solved my issue.